# how to iterate over column and each iteration result save in result dataframe python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have one dataframe with multiple columns ,i need to calculate same thing for all columns , is there any way to do this ? i have many columns so can not do one by one

```
df=pd.DataFrame({r'A':[1,24,69,67],r'A\0001\delta':[1,46,454,67],r'A\0002\delta':[1,46,454,67],r'A\00100\delta':[1,46,70,67]})

i want to calculate:
diff=df[r'A\0001\delta'].diff()
if diff greater than 60 save row in result dataframe
```

same thing i want to do for more than 100 columns and want to save results in result dataframe by rows

Comment: Please edit you question to include the expected output for the given sample dataframe.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Actually this is just example , if you have one csv with 1000 columns , there are 10 columns for each unique type that column name contains 0001  for each unique set i need to apply same calculation and save results in dataframe , in result dataframe column name will be unique , just need to add column to mention result rows belong to which group

Comment: You want to save the row if one value is greater than 60 for the row or all values are greater than 60. In your example, what do you want to keep? That's what @ShubhamSharma means.

Comment: @Corralien all values greater than 60

Answer (score 1):

At least one value greater than 60 on a row

```py
>>> df.loc[df.diff().gt(60).any(axis=1)]

    A  A\0001\delta  A\0002\delta  A\00100\delta
2  69           454           454             70
```

All values greater than 60 on a row:

```py
>>> df.loc[df.diff().gt(60).all(axis=1)]

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, A\0001\delta, A\0002\delta, A\00100\delta]
Index: []
```

Comment: This is probably not what you want but since there is no example of a result ...

Comment: i am just looking for method to iterate over columns, first need calculation for all columns which contain 0001 and then for all columns contain 0002   and so on

Comment: Ok so update your post and for your example, show us the expect output.